# eBay Trading SOAP API — invalid AppId?

Tags: python, soap, ebay-api

I'm trying to get my first call through to the eBay Sandbox using the SOAP API

I keep getting an **Invalid AppId** response.  I quadruple checked that I do in fact have the proper AppIp for the Sandbox environment.  eBay documentation is fairly unhelpful.

I'm using SUDS and Python 2.7 to make the calls.

**Request**

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=GetCategories&appid=MyAppId&siteid=2&version=785&routing=default)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o
rg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <ns0:RequesterCredentials ns1:mustUnderstand="0">
         <eBayAuthToken>MySandboxUserAuthToken</eBayAuthToken>
      </ns0:RequesterCredentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:GetCategoriesRequest>
         <ns0:DetailLevel xsi:type="ns0:GetCategoriesRequestType">
            <ns0:DetailLevel>ReturnAll</ns0:DetailLevel>
            <ns0:Version>785</ns0:Version>
            <ns0:ErrorHandling/>
            <ns0:WarningLevel>High</ns0:WarningLevel>
            <ns0:LevelLimit>1</ns0:LevelLimit>
         </ns0:DetailLevel>
      </ns0:GetCategoriesRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
...
<FaultDetail>
   <ErrorCode>127</ErrorCode>
   <Severity>Error</Severity>
   <DetailedMessage>API application &quot;{0}&quot; invalid.</DetailedMessage>
</FaultDetail>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your `appId` in the [test tool](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up dropping suds and Soap to use ebaysdk that wraps some of the xml codes.